# AWS : retrieving EC2 instance id linked to a beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

How to get the instance id linked to an EBS environment (with boto for instance):

(the 'EnvironmentId' param is not the EC2 AMI id)

```
def get_environment_instance(self, env_name):
        """
        Returns the environment instance id
        """
        response = self.ebs.describe_environments(application_name=self.app_name,environment_names=[env_name],include_deleted=False)
        envs = response['DescribeEnvironmentsResponse']['DescribeEnvironmentsResult']['Environments']
        for env in envs[:]:
                out('---'+  env['EnvironmentId'])
        return None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the `describe_environment_resources` method, not `describe_environments`.  That should return all of the AWS resources used by the environment, including instance ID's of all EC2 instances.